# what a downvote means to you?

Tags: discussion

I always hesitate to downvote a question or an answer that I would flag anyway, mostly because most of the time it comes from new users.

A few months later, I still could deserve some downvotes for one liner answers with a single link...but I try to correct that, mostly because I got nice comments explaining me to proceed differently.

So what does a downvote mean to you and should I / we use it more or less or for very specific cases ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting some Stack Exchange resources below.

## [Help > Privileges > Vote Down](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

> #### What is voting down?
>
> Voting down, also known as "casting downvotes", is how the community indicates which questions and answers are least useful.
>
> #### When should I vote down?
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes *cost you a tiny bit of reputation* on top of that; use them wisely.
>
> #### What are the alternatives to down-voting?
>
> The [up-vote privilege](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.
>
> Instead of voting down:
>
> - If the post is spammy or offensive, [**flag** it](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
> - If the question is duplicate or off-topic, [**flag** it for moderator attention](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
> - If something is wrong, please [leave a **comment**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) or [**edit** the post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) to correct it.

## [Stack Exchange > Meta > When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/226837)

> ### Questions
>
> To downvote a question, downvote immediately. If there's scope for improvement, comment and downvote. You can always undownvote if its improved. [Read more](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)
>
> Downvote if:
>
> - It's unclear
> - It's a [plzsendtehcodez](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plzsendtehcodez) or similar question with no effort from the OP
> - It's localized (will probably be useless to the world)
>
> Note that I tend to upvote *questions* when their answers explain something pretty well. This is probably wrong, but that's just me.
>
> Do NOT downvote just because:
>
> - The question uses incorrect grammar (as long as it is comprehensible)
> - The question has bad, (but clear) code; the question uses bad coding practices; the premise of the program is wrong. In this case, just comment "why haven't you done blah?". If you're answering, you can append that to your answer instead. ([I've done that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260058/1198729)). **Remember, voting is to filter *post* quality, not *code* quality or *OP* quality.**. Also, there are legitimate uses for *everything*, [even `eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197769/1260906).
>
> ### Answers
>
> With answers, again, downvote immediately, comment, undownvote if fixed. With newbies I tend to be more lax, I comment first and downvote if they decide not to listen. But again, that's just me.
>
> Try to comment whenever applicable when downvoting.
>
> Downvote if:
>
> - Does not answer the question. Flag at your discretion.
> - Makes no sense
> - [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/226837) post with minimal answer: This depends upon the answer really.
> - Code-only answer: A post *must* be useful to People From The Future™. Nobody's going to have the exact same code with the exact same issue ([Well, maybe not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)). People From The Future™ should have an explanation of *why* the code is wrong/bad/whatever so that they learn something.
> - [Link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)-[only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/226837) [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/226837)
> - Is wrong (in your opinion).
> - Bad coding practices. Unlike questions, the answer should use good coding practices. For questions and answers, *post quality* is differently measured. For questions, it has to do with the actual question more than the code. For code-only answers, bad coding practices are..well.. *bad*. In the case of a good explanation with bad code, downvote, comment, undownvote. Or abstain from voting and comment. Either is fine, it's up to you.
>
> Do NOT downvote just because:
>
> - It's a competitor. Voting is for *post quality*, and you end up harming the system. Also, upvoting competing answers gets you [something shiny](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/119/sportsmanship).
> - Again, grammar that does not affect comprehensibility too much.

I hope this helps. See also [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/226837).

Comment: very useful, I'll keep this in mind : Remember, voting is to filter post quality, not code quality or OP quality