# Is there a way to know who downvoted to ask him/her why and improve our post?

Tags: support

I got 2 questions suddenly donwnvoted and I would really like to improve them but as no comment was leaved, I don't even know what is the problem...
See :

- my answer here : [Account uniqueness guaranteed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/account-uniqueness-guaranteed/4301#4301)
- a question here : [Where to find the documents matching the dao proposals hash?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/where-to-find-the-documents-matching-the-dao-proposals-hash)

If anyone have comments to improve them, I would be pleased to edit my posts.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of your question, No, you wont be able to see who voted how on which post. **Not even moderators** can see who voted what.

And I think it's not important, It's clearly more important to [encourage users to explain why they downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/226837).

Answer (score 1):

I am the one who downvoted the first because i thought the other answer had better quality with figures notably, and because I think this shouldn't be the accepted answer, which is not up to you I know ;)
I even find the # of grains of sand more cleat than what you wrote.

I could have commented why i downvoted you, you're correct and apologies for that.

That said, as described in [enter link description here](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/what-a-downvote-means-to-you) it's more about giving a point to one and not to another, to discriminate between good and better answer, that is not about OP quality, I just felt that the other answer is better so gave point to one and removed one to yours.

Comment: Oh don't be sorry, I don't take it personally ! I just wanted to know the reason of the downvote to improve my posts.

Comment: no you're right I should have commented as to why, sometimes i read posts and +1 or -1 like a monkey, je recommencerais pas !

Comment: By the way, I will downvote and flag your answer as it's absolutely not an answer to my question. Non j'déconne ;) But I guess that your answer also means that there's no way for me to know who downvoted and contact her/him.

Comment: lol ;) no I think there is no way of knowing, maybe with moderator tools