# Very low quality content not catched by system?

Tags: support

My concern is regarding the answer on this question: [Exceptions when compiling a contract using Solidity version 0.6.0 on Remix](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78557/exceptions-when-compiling-a-contract-using-solidity-version-0-6-0-on-remix/78558?noredirect=1#comment99126_78558)

The answer although was accepted as solution, it does not give any technical fact or evidence, it just remits to go a chatroom, no specifics given on the name of the channel.

I followed the indication from [meta ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/encouraging-commenting-before-down-voting/466#466):
Is it of very low quality? Vote down, leave a comment, and flag it for moderator attention!

The user that responded the question clearly took it personal rather than in a constructive way, which I'm surprised as being a user with 2k+ does not know that for a regular Joe and overall users this answer does not provide further insight. So instead of having at least a snippet, the user is remitted to look somewhere else.

I'm interesting in knowing whether the answer got caught by the low quality content of the system and what was the score. I see this being possible in other SE site [gardening](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/how-does-the-system-recognize-qualify-low-quality-content)

Also interest in knowing if this answer can be taken down as it is or how many flags are required to take it down if possible as this answer is not only very low quality, but the respondent lacks of commitment to add anything meaningful.